# merge sort with pthread using struct

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct, pthreads

I'm trying to sort some numbers stored in an array within each given segments.

```
typedef struct _sortee{
    int * nums;//array of numbers to be sorted
    size_t num_elems;//# of elements in each segment
    size_t segment_count;//# of segments
    int **ptrs;//pointers to the array of numbers
    int index;
}sortee;
```

The problem is that every time a thread is created, the number in sortlist->index is changed, so sometimes not the right segment is sorted. I know to fix this I have to pass in a array of the struct I created as the 4th parameter in the pthread_create but I can't come up with an idea since the struct has the array to be sorted too.

```
pthread_t tid[sortlist->segment_count];
for(i=0; i<(int)sortlist->segment_count; i++){
    sortlist->index = i;
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sort, sortlist);
}


for(i=0; i<(int)sortlist->segment_count; i++){
    sortlist->index = i;
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}
```

This is the very first part of the sorting algorithm. After running this I have another merge function to sort the rest.

```
void *sort(void *ptr) {
sortee *sortlist = (sortee *)ptr;

qsort(sortlist->ptrs[sortlist->index], sortlist->num_elems, sizeof(int), comp);
fprintf(stderr, "Sorted %d elements.\n", (int)sortlist->num_elems); 
return sortlist;
}
```

Could someone give me a little bit of idea? Thanks! Sorry if my English is hard to understand...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Each thread needs its own copy of the data structure, identifying the sub-range of the array that it is to sort.  The final merge will, presumably, combine all the separately sorted segments into a single merged one.

Comment: consider mutex/locking.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you hav an array so that each pthread has its own tid, have another array so each pthread can have it's own index: you could pass a different struct to each pthread, which stored that pthread's index as well as a pointer to the struct they all share.